# How to fix npm ENOENT error in create-react-app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npx

[I'm trying to create-react-app but it's showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWhPh.png)

I've tried

- npm cache clean --force
- npx create-react-app .

Also used this but same issue occurs

- npm install -g create-react-app

can anyone suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible to copy the log here? Apart from this, can you please mention the versions of npm and Node?

Answer (score 4):

update npm

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

it will solve the problme

Answer (score 2):

## npx is used for the libraries in node_modules in your project

Since you used `-g` (meaning global) to install create react app you should use

```
npm create-react-app
```

If you add `create-react-app` to your package json with

```
npm install create-react-app
```

you can then use `npx` to run the command.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your create react app version is compatible with your machine's node version. Upgrade or downgrade accordingly to match the two. This fixed the issue at my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I got this mistake once and the reason was because I ran the "npm " commands without haven't "cd" into my react project.

i had the folder structure like:

- Project

  - react-project (..contains all react boiler-plate code and files)

I was running "npm start" while been in "Project" directory. you have to "cd" into your react-app (..in this case 'react-project') before running any npm commands.