# Getting this error messages when using npx create-react-app on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, npx

```
(base) akj@JammyJellyfish:~/Desktop/Social-Media-App/client$ npx create-react-app .
npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path /home/akj/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/akj/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/akj/.npm/_logs/2023-01-09T14_52_48_118Z-debug-0.log
(base) akj@JammyJellyfish:~/Desktop/Social-Media-App/client$
```

When trying to create a new react app using create-react-app generator I seem to run into this error. Not sure how to fix it. I've use npx create-react-app many time before but recently it has stopped working. Any suggestions? I am currently using UBUNTU Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

Comment: Could you clearing your NPM cache?

Comment: Also, this specific answer might siuggest a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521425/19135131